# Performance of sklearn KNN classifier with Minkowski distance

Tags: python, scikit-learn

this is more of a general discussion, but I'm noticing something weird with the `sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier` function under Minkowski distance with p>=3.

Now, p=2 is pretty fast, p=1 is slightly slower but fine, but p=3 is incredibly slow, even with one neighbour. Does anyone know what causes this problem/know a solution for it?

```
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
clf_knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=1, p=3, metric="minkowski")
clf_knn.fit(X_train, y_train)
clf_knn.predict(X_test)
```